# Can the parameter in data class be var in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, data-class

I'm a beginner of Kotlin, I have read some sample code about data class, it seems that the parameter are all val type just like Code A

I need to change some values of data class MSetting, so I design the Code B, could you tell me whether the Code B is good way?

**Code A**

```
data class MSetting (
        val _id: Long, 
        val name: String,
        val createdDate: Long,
        val description: String
)
```

**Code B**

```
data class MSetting (
        var _id: Long, 
        var name: String,
        var createdDate: Long,
        var description: String
)
```

Comment: Despite the name, data classes are neither immutable per so, nor ar they value types. Those simply don't exist on the JVM. For now.

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73812090/1179638

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> it seems that the parameter are all `val` type...

**NO**

> could you tell me whether the Code B is good way?

The difference between `val` and `var`: Properties declared with `val` can't be updated over time; its just like constants in java. Properties declared with `var` can be changed overtime.

It totally depends on your requirement. If you need to change properties over time then go for `var`; `val` otherwise. You can mix both in a object without any issue.

Read more about properties in Kotlin documentation here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html

Comment: This is not correct @Rohit5k2, Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73812090/1179638

Comment: @AtulBhardwaj it technically is correct, it just doesn't mention that using `var` as a data class parameter fundamentally changes how this particular data class will behave (which is indeed explained nicely in the answer you've linked).

Answer (score 17):

The accepted answer is misleading. Yes, you can use `var` arguments in `data class` constructor. But you should avoid it at all costs because it defeats the purpose of `data class`.

Consider this example:

```
data class Text(
    val x: String,
    var y: Int,
)

fun main() {
    val t = Text("4124", 1)
    val a = t.hashCode()
    t.y = 125
    val b = t.hashCode()
    println(a)
    println(b)
}
```

The output will be something like:

```
49532514
49532638
```

This means, object `t` cannot be used in `Map/Set`, because it's `hashCode` isn't constant which will lead to ghost-objects in these collections.

The proper way to have modifiable field in `data class` is:

```
data class Text(
   val x: String,
) {
   var y: Int
}
```

This way `y` isn't included in generated `equals, hashCode, toString` and problem with `Map/Set` is avoided.

See kotlin doc for this: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html#properties-declared-in-the-class-body

Comment: Good point and it's really strange that language creators doesn't care even about warning if that type of usage occurs

Answer (score 2):

I like to use val as a rule of thumb because it makes data class immutable. Of course I am using var but only if it is necessary. Why it is better to make data class immutable? [read this](https://dev.to/rapasoft/on-immutability-in-kotlin-251k).